# Can I set a folder in view()->composer() function using AppserviceProvider.php?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

So i have folder 'posts' where i have 3 blade templates. I want to use some variable in all this templates. Therefore i added array of my templates. How can i set a folder with this files instead of array ?

What i have:

```
 view()->composer(['admin.posts.index' , 'admin.posts.edit' , 'admin.posts.create'], function($view){
     $view->with('current_user', Auth::user());
  });
```

What i want:

```
 view()->composer('folder_name', function($view){
     $view->with('current_user', Auth::user());
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure this is in any way related to [tag:composer-php]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try with a wildcard:

```
view()->composer('admin.posts.*', ...);
```